# Is it possible to concatenate a string with series of number?

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, matlab-uitable

I have a string (eg. 'STA') and I want to make a cell array that will be a concatenation of my sting with a numbers from 1 to X.

I want the code to do something like the fore loop here below:

```
for i = 1:Num
    a = [{a}  {strcat('STA',num2str(i))}]
end
```

I want the end results to be in the form of {<1xNum cell>}

```
a = 'STA1' 'STA2' 'STA3' ...
```

(I want to set this to a uitable in the ColumnFormat array)

```
ColumnFormat = {{a},...                 % 1
             'numeric',...              % 2
             'numeric'};                % 3
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with combination of **NUM2STR** (converts numbers to strings), **CELLSTR** (converts strings to cell array), **STRTRIM** (removes extra spaces)and **STRCAT** (combines with another string) functions.

You need `(:)` to make sure the numeric vector is column.

```
x = 1:Num;
a = strcat( 'STA', strtrim( cellstr( num2str(x(:)) ) ) );
```

---

As an alternative for matrix with more dimensions I have this helper function:

```
function c = num2cellstr(xx, varargin)
%Converts matrix of numeric data to cell array of strings

c = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x,varargin{:}), num2cell(xx), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about starting with STA1, but this should get you a list that starts with STA (from which I guess you could remove the first entry).

```
N = 5;
[X{1:N+1}] = deal('STA');
a = genvarname(X);
a = a(2:end);
```

Comment: Interesting approach. If you need numbers in a sequence starting from 1. `X=repmat({'STA'},1,N+1);` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
N = 10;
a = cell(1,N);
for i = 1:N
    a(i) = {['STA',num2str(i)]};
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to have it without a FOR loop?